# Single page site - drupal 7

Tags: 7, theming

I am trying to add multiple pages to my home page (about, contact), I assumed I do this in page--front.tpl. How to I call or pull in page nodes into my template?

Comment: When you say you want to "add multiple pages to my homepage", do you mean provide links to pages?  I'm assuming this is the case but it isn't quite clear.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like something perfecly suited to [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels).

> **An Overview of Panels**
>
> The Panels module allows a site administrator to
> create customized layouts for multiple uses. At its core it is a drag
> and drop content manager that lets you visually design a layout and
> place content within that layout. Integration with other systems
> allows you to create nodes that use this, landing pages that use this,
> and even override system pages such as taxonomy and the node page so
> that you can customize the layout of your site with very fine grained
> permissions.

Just create a panel page with the content you want displayed in a list, and then make this panel page your front page.

There are loads of tutorials/help on the [project documentation](http://drupal.org/node/496278) page if you've never used it before.

Comment: Would I be able to add jquery to scroll through the pages? I am trying to do a single page website with say basic page content in drupal that scrolls the website using the main menu. I want to use jquery and ajax to pull in different background images also.

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem.  There's [jQuery Scrollto](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_scrollto) that implements the plugin that you'd want, although it's only available for Drupal 6.  It shouldn't be that hard to implement in in 7 though.

Comment: You could also try [SmoothScroll](http://drupal.org/sandbox/egomac/1354422), although it's only a sandbox implementation at the moment.  Waiting for a full project release.

Comment: Great! thanks, I am checking out panels now and looks like this is what I need.

Answer (score 2):

There is a module that you can use: [Single Page Website](http://drupal.org/project/single_page_website).

> This module provide the ability to display the content of all menu items of the menu that you indicate in settings on the Single Page Website module.
>   On the page 'single_page' the links in the menu will be replaced to the links to the correspondent anchors.
>   You can set URL 'single_page' as front page of your site, and your visitors will see the Single Page Website. But it will be the site managed by Drupal 7.
>
> This appoach is good for the small personal websites and promotional pages.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a single-page site, then all you want is a page.tpl.php file in your template directory for your theme.

What I recommend is you create your Contact and About pages utilizing the Basic Page content type, and before you save each make sure that under "Menu settings" towards the bottom, you check off "Provide a menu link" and "<Main Menu>" selected as the parent item.  This will place the About and Contact page in the main menu at the top level.  Also, under "Publishing options" verify that each is published.

Once you have created the pages and configured them so they show up in the main menu, then go into your Blocks configuration and place the Main menu block in the header region (or whatever region you wish, depends on what you want for a layout).  That will expose those menu links on every page, assuming the header region is rendered in page.tpl.php.

Definitely ask for clarification if you're confused, I'll be here all day.

Comment: I want to actually see the contact, about, home, history pages all from the home page (the full content), but also, be able to have other pages linked from there(default main menu) My main question is the single page site on the front page. I want to pull in specific page node content ($page['about'] into the home page).